# ARKit – Is it possible to add a SCNNode while ARSession is paused?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit

I want to add SCNNode while ARSCNView session is pause.

Is it possible in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can add a node to the `SCNScene` in case your model isn't tethered with `ARAnchor`. However, when the session is paused, you cannot add an anchor with a corresponding model to the scene.